# How to get the last selected item in multiselect ListBox?

Tags: .net, winforms, listbox

How to get the last selected item in a .Net Forms multiselect ListBox? Apparently if I select an item in the listbox and then select another 10 the selected item is the first one.

I would like to obtain the last element that I selected/deselected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would take this general approach:

Listen for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and scan through the `SelectedIndices` collection every time.

Keep a separate list of all selected indices, appending ones that have not been in the list, removing those that have been de-selected.

The separate list will contain the indexes in the chronological order they were selected by the user. The last element always is the most recently selected index.

```
// for the sake of the example, I defined a single List<int>
List<int> listBox1_selection = new List<int>();

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TrackSelectionChange((ListBox)sender, listBox1_selection);
}

private void TrackSelectionChange(ListBox lb, List<int> selection)
{
    ListBox.SelectedIndexCollection sic = lb.SelectedIndices;
    foreach (int index in sic)
        if (!selection.Contains(index)) selection.Add(index);

    foreach (int index in new List<int>(selection))
        if (!sic.Contains(index)) selection.Remove(index);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you have both have been helpful

Answer (score 6):

In the mouse click event of listbox use following code:

```
private void ListBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    string s = ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location)].ToString();

    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure I understand the question, but the last selected item will be the last in the SelectedItems array, so something like this should work:

```
ListItem i = list.SelectedItems[list.SelectedItems.Length-1];
```

Comment: That returns the last item in the list that is currently selected, which is not the same thing as the last item the user selected.  For example, if the user selected 'item 3', the 'item 1', your solution will always return 'item 3'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 private void listBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int jj = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
        object Test = listBox1.Items[jj];
        object LatestItemSelected;
        if(listBox1.SelectedItems.Contains(Test))
            LatestItemSelected = Test;
    }
```

Obviously *LatestItemSelected* is redundant and is there to emphasize that you have found your item.

Answer (score 0):

This is way I've done it in VB.

When you refresh the list box you have to re-dimension the array.

```
  Dim SelectedAry(-1) As Integer

  Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim LastOne As Integer = -1
        ' First time there no elements in the preserved array
        If SelectedAry.Length = 0 Then
              If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
                    LastOne = 0
              End If
        Else
              'If the SelectedIndices array is larger than the preserved SelectedAry - means that another one had been selected
              If ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Count >= SelectedAry.Length Then
                    For i = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1
                          'Go through both arrays comparing the values until there is a mismatch
                          'This means that the value in the  SelectesIndices is the last one to be added
                          If ListBox1.SelectedIndices(i) <> SelectedAry(i) Then
                                LastOne = i
                                Exit For
                          End If
                    Next
              End If
        End If
        ' Copy the Listbox selectedindices array into the SelectedAry which is preserved for the next selected index change
        ReDim SelectedAry(ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Count)
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1
              SelectedAry(i) = ListBox1.SelectedIndices(i)
        Next
        ' Display the last one added
        If LastOne >= 0 Then
              Dim FileName As String = txtFolder.Text & "\" & ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndices(LastOne)).ToString
              Display_File(FileName)
        Else
        End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: The question asks for a .net solution not a vb solution.

Comment: That's a VB.Net solution (still .Net)

Answer (score 0):

using a bit of reflection to get the value of FocusedIndex which is an internal property of ListBox you can get the last focused on item.

```
int lastSelectedIndex = (int)typeof(ListBox).GetProperty("FocusedIndex",BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(myListBox,null);
SelectedItemType mySelectedItem = myListBox.Items[lastSelectedIndex] as SelectedItemType;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(listbox) or Keyboard.FocusedElement to return the last item you selected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem in VBA...the idea is to record previous selections in a hidden label...then compare all of the selected items in the listbox vs. the recorded previous selections...if it doesn't exist in the label then this IS the last selected item. I've tested it and it works...you will have to tweak the code a bit but the idea works for me.

```
Private Sub ListBox2_Change()
    
    'Preview Doc
    Previous_Selections = Me.Label2.Caption
    
    'This logic figures out the last selected item if you already have existing selections
    For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
         If ListBox2.Selected(i) Then
            MyItem = ListBox2.List(i)
            
            'Check if this is a new selection or and old one
            If IsIn(MyItem, Previous_Selections) = False Then
            
                'This is a new selection
                'Record new selection for as 'previous' for next time
                For n = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
                    If ListBox2.Selected(n) Then Selections = Selections & ListBox2.List(n) & ", "
                Next
                
                'Preview last selected item
                FullPath = Me.ListBox1.Value & "\" & MyItem
                Me.Label2.Caption = Selections
                Call Preview_Document(FullPath)
                Exit Sub
            End If
         End If
    Next i
    
    
   
End Sub
```