# .NET Multi-Select Listbox - How to get Item just selected?

Tags: c#, vb.net, listbox

In .NET there doesn't seem to be a property to find the item *just* selected in a multi-select listbox; SelectedIndex always shows the first selected item. From memory VB6 had the ListIndex property that changed accordingly... Why remove a useful property ?!

**Duplicate:** [How to get the last selected item in multiselect ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305555/how-to-get-the-last-selected-item-in-multiselect-listbox)

Comment: Voted to close: "exact duplicate".  Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305555/how-to-get-the-last-selected-item-in-multiselect-listbox.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own listbox that enherits from listbox and overrride the onclick?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not create a hidden field and copy the value selected each time on a click event into that field.  That should always contain the last item selected by the client.