# On SelectionChanged event (ListBox: SelectionMode=Multiple), the FIRST selected item is always returned not the CURRENT

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

My ListBox.SelectedValue returns the first selected item and not the currently selected item. (Currently selected item means that aside from the selected ITEMS, I am also displaying the **last item** selected)

My SelectionMode this time is Multiple not Single.

```
private void ListBoxSource_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fileSelected = (FileFound)this.ListBoxSource.SelectedValue; 
        BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
        bmpImage.BeginInit();
        bmpImage.UriSource = new Uri(fileSelected.FileFullName, UriKind.Absolute);
        bmpImage.EndInit();

        Image1.Source = bmpImage;

     }
```

Now, instead of doing it on the event, I tried Binding my Image control to the ListBoxSource **BUT** nothing is displayed.

```
 Source="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxSource, Path=SelectedItems
```

Is theres a chance to bind it? or what is wrong with my SelectionChangedEvent code?

Comment: do I understand right, you have multiple items selected already, then you select one more item and you want to get a reference to this last selected item?

Comment: @StaWho exactly...because i already have other listbox that shows all the selected items. I Just want to show the last selected item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the last selected item, you'll want the last index of the `SelectedItems` property.

```
var lb = (sender as ListBox);
lb.SelectedItems[lb.SelectedItems.Count - 1];
```

**EDIT**

To get the last selected item as a FileFound object, I *think* you want this:

```
var lb = (sender as ListBox);
FileFound lastSelectedFile = 
                 (FileFound)lb.SelectedItems[lb.SelectedItems.Count - 1];
```

Comment: would that be faster performance wise than grabbing the reference from `AddedItems`?

Comment: @StaWho - meh - either should work - I doubt performance would matter either way.  I +1'd your answer accordingly

Comment: @AdamRackis I know my question is a bit confusing But this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305555/how-to-get-the-last-selected-item-in-multiselect-listbox) is exactly what I wanted to accomplish. ONLY, the code is already old. Even VS doesnt recognize lots of properties..

Comment: @user1078782 - do my and StaWho's answers not accomplish this?

Comment: @AdamRackis both doesnt work for me. because Ill be using the selectedItem/selectedValue as my source to my Image Control. I am retrieving "FileFullName" property of my "FileFound" class which is binded to my listBox (see my implementation above).

Comment: @user1078782 - see my last edit.  It's untested, but that should be very very close to what you're wanting

Comment: Yes.it is.. Great job..thanks a lot. The .length should be .Count.

Comment: @user1078782 - cool!  And thanks for the correction - I guess I've been answering JavaScript questions too long if I thought IList had a length property :)

Comment: @AdamRackis :) I really appreciate your help.. sorry for my english

Comment: @AdamRackis always 100 ways to skin a cat :)

Answer (score 3):

Look at `e.AddedItems` and `e.RemovedItems`. not sure what you mean by `currently selected item`, if you have multiselect?

[edit]

if you want last selected item it will be

```
var lastItem = e.AddedItems[e.AddedItems.Count - 1];
```

Comment: I edit it.. please read again the first paragraph.. Meaning if selected 3 items, I want to show the 3rd item in an image control.