# Tooltip text not updating in listbox when I move up the list

Tags: powershell, forms, listbox, tooltip

I have a powershell script where I look for and sort some files to populate a multiselect listbox. I added a function and a handler to show a tooltip with the "last modified" date whenever I click an element from the list. However, after selecting an item, the tooltip text value will not update if I select a different item in a position above that one, showing that one's last modified date instead. Can someone please help me understad why this is happening? I thought it had to do with the sorting, but the result is the same without sorting it. My code should always take the last one selected, no?

```
#MAIN WINDOW
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(620,400)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.FormBorderStyle = "Sizable"

#SOURCE FILES FOLDER
$sourceFolder = "C:\Users\me\Downloads"

#FILE LISTBOX
$sourceListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$sourceListBox.SelectionMode = "MultiSimple"
$sourceListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,310)
$sourceListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,30)

#SEARCH FOR FILES
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter "*.pdf" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$sourceListBox.Items.AddRange($sourceFiles)
$form.Controls.Add($sourceListBox)

#TOOLTIP
$toolTip = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip

#UPDATE TOOLTIP FROM LAST SELECTED ITEM
function ShowLastModifiedDateTooltip {
    $selectedItems = $sourceListBox.SelectedItems
    if ($selectedItems.Count -gt 0) {
        $lastSelectedItem = $selectedItems[$selectedItems.Count - 1]
        $sourcePath = Join-Path $sourceFolder $lastSelectedItem
        $lastModifiedDate = (Get-Item $sourcePath).LastWriteTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
        $toolTip.SetToolTip($sourceListBox, "Modified: $lastModifiedDate")
    }
}

#HANDLE CLICKS IN THE LISTBOX
$sourceListBox.Add_Click({
    ShowLastModifiedDateTooltip
})
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: This seems to be working for me on PowerShell 7.3.8. What version are you running. I had to add `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` at the top.

Comment: I'm running PS 5.1.
It doesn't put the earliest "modified date" in the tooltip if you click a recent pdf after selecting an older one? I tried "write-host $lastModifiedDate" and it seems like it's just appending the dates to the variable.

Comment: It is because of the order of the array `$sourceListBox.SelectedItems`. It does not add the next item selection at the end of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the logic from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/305601/15339544) to always get the index of the lastly selected item from your `ListBox`. In addition, you should use the [`SelectedIndexChanged` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) instead of the `Click` event.

Using a custom set for the demo:

```bash
#FILE LISTBOX
$sourceListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$sourceListBox.SelectionMode = "MultiSimple"
$sourceListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,310)
$sourceListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,30)
$sourceListBox.Items.AddRange(@('hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
$form.Controls.Add($sourceListBox)

#TOOLTIP
$toolTip = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip
$tracker = [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]]::new()
$sourceListBox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $indices = [int[]] $sourceListBox.SelectedIndices
    $tracker.RemoveAll({ -not $sourceListBox.SelectedIndices.Contains($args[0]) })
    $tracker.AddRange([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Except($indices, $tracker))

    if ($tracker.Count) {
        $lastSelected = $sourceListBox.Items[$tracker[-1]]
        $toolTip.SetToolTip($this, "Selected Item: $lastSelected")
    }
})
```

[image: demo]